# How to Convert SizeTransition to FadeTransition for Flutter Codelab

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm new to Flutter and Dart. Hopes to get some guide on a tutorial exercise I'm stuck.

I'm following Flutter Codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6 and able to do everything.

There's an exercise it ask us to do that is

*Create a fade-in animation effect by wrapping the Container in a FadeTransition widget instead of a SizeTransition.*

The code as below

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new SizeTransition(
    sizeFactor: new CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut),
    axisAlignment: 0.0,
    child: new Container(
      // ... other codes ...
    ),
  );
}
```

So I change to FadeTransition, which requires `opacity` of type `Animation<Double>`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FadeTransition(
    opacity: animation
    child: new Container(
      // ... other codes ...
    ),
  );
}
```

How could I create or send in the `animation`? (the above code will have `animation` unrecognizable).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
opacity: Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(animationController),
```

`CurvedAnimation` is used for non-linear animation.

See more detail here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, by referring to https://proandroiddev.com/getting-your-hands-dirty-with-flutter-basic-animations-6b9f21fa7d17 and modify accordingly.

So to have `FadeTransition`, basically just replace

```
opacity: animation
```

with

```
opacity: new CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn),
```

This is not ideal as every time a message is inserted, it is creating a new `CurveAnimation`, but for the sake of concise solution, I make it so.